# Center image above text in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, center

I am trying to make the main page for a website.
I want three images with text underneath but the images are not centered above the text. Here is the jsFiddle.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rubinoff/bCv5Z/)

```
 <div class="row" style="text-align:center">

            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-8">
                 <img src="http://s27.postimg.org/5emjkk14v/image.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="height:180px;width:180px;" />
                <h4> Vaccinations</h4>
                <p>Dogs and cats are susceptible to a variety of illnesses that can be completely prevented by following the appropriate vaccination schedule.</p>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-8">
                <img src="http://s27.postimg.org/5emjkk14v/image.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="height:180px;width:180px;" />
                <h4>Checkups</h4>
                <p>Regular checkups are a key factor in pet wellness, and can often unearth problems that could lead to health issues down the road.  </p>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-8">
                  <img src="http://s27.postimg.org/5emjkk14v/image.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="height:180px;width:180px;" />
                <h4> Senior Pets</h4>
                <p>Senior pets generally require more medical attention than their younger counterparts, just as senior humans do. So when is a pet considered “senior”? </p>

            </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the left and right margins of the images to auto

```
.col-md-4.col-xs-8 img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Updated [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bCv5Z/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.img-responsive{display:inline-block}
```

Comment: What's this code about? You should include brief about solution you are suggesting!

Comment: Very simply it is to solve this problem. In his fiddle, he is using Bootstrapwhich has img-responsive for image responsive.. however that class also has display:block that causes the exact issue. I am sure anyone who is experienced in Bootstrap framework will come across this atleast once. So not much explanation needed. Just overwrite the img-responsive display.